module works on jquery 1.7.1 but not on jquery 2.1.1
I have a module on my Cms that works very well with the jquery 1.7.1 but not works (nothing happens when i click on the button) with the jquery 2.1.1.
I send you the code below :
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method/givemr&ismr=1',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#mr_cp_search, #mr_pays_search'),
        dataType: 'json',   
        success: function(json) {
   
            $('.warning').remove();
           
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }
           
            if (json['output']) {
                $('#resultats_pt_relais').html(json['output']);               
            }
        }
    });    

I am not good at jquery so can you tell me if something has changed between the 2 versions.
Thanks for your help.
Alex
0
I have the following errors :
La ressource à l’adresse « https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapstraction/mxn/master/source/mxn.js?(openlayers) » a été bloquée en raison d’un type MIME (« text/plain ») incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). index.php window.controllers/Controllers est obsolète. Veuillez ne pas l’utiliser pour détecter l’agent utilisateur (UA). OpenLayers.js:550:418 La ressource à l’adresse « https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapstraction/mxn/master/source/mxn.js?(openlayers) » a été bloquée en raison d’un type MIME (« text/plain ») incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). index.php Échec du chargement pour l’élément dont la source est « https://raw.github.com/mapstraction/mxn/master/source/mxn.js?(openlayers) ». index.php:136:113 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function http://dem22.opencart.ovh/index.php?route=checkout/checkout:912 index.php:912:28

check your browser dev console and network tab for possible errors. If found anything then add it here in your question, but before that try to resolve it at your end. I am talking about these 2 tabs: https://prnt.sc/gbjbhHLXMP8o

jQuery v1 & v2 are too old, you should consider using the latest supported version of jQuery instead. FYI, the latest OpenCart version uses jQuery 3.6: https://demo.opencart.com/

i need to use jquery 2.1.1 because the module is for opencart 2.3

hi Death-is-the-real-truth, i have edit the first message with the errors Can you help me?
